# Monitoring processes/services Error by Zabbix over HPe Server

Tags: hp-proliant, snmp, zabbix, ilo, hpe

Would you mind sharing your experience with me?
I monitor the ilo HP server with Zabbix
Whenever there is a problem with the RAM or hard disk on the server, I receive a critical alarm through this OID.
1.3.6.1.4.1.232.6.1.3.0
It's just that, even if they replace the RAM or the disk and the problem is solved, this alarm still remains
Snmpwalk also returns a value of 4 for error items

Answer (score 0):

The `cpqHeMibCondition` status you're referring to by OID includes an IML status condition into its processing. Whenever you have a hardware issue, an IML message is being recorded stating problem nature and severity and until this message has not been cleared from the IML the `cpqHeMibCondition` will not return to OK.

To resolve it you should login via iLO or use System Manager Homepage if your installation supports it and clear failure/warning messages from the IML.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve it without clearing the IML.
Whenever I have solved a problem, I just tick the Mark As Repaired box for it!
I also rebooted the iLO.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).